# Track use rotation angle using Microsoft Kinect SDK

Tags: kinect

I'm implementing a WPF application which can track the rotation of the user. THe bisc idea is kinect is placed in a constant place. User comes in front of the kinect and he/she can rotate 360 degrees. I want to track how much of degrees user has rotated. I used following method to track it. But it seems like the function is not accurate and when user is facing with 0 degrees it shows it as 180 and also it gives minus values as well.

```
public static double GetShoulderRotation(this Skeleton skeleton)
    {
        Joint leftShoulder = skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft];
        Joint rightShoulder = skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight];
        if (leftShoulder.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked ||
            rightShoulder.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
        {
            return Double.NaN;
        }
        else
        {
            return (Math.Atan2(
                rightShoulder.Position.Z - leftShoulder.Position.Z,
                leftShoulder.Position.X - rightShoulder.Position.X)*180.0/Math.PI);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please give a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommended to use the rotation of bone between hipcenter and spine. When a person is standing in face-front to Kinect, Hipcenter.Z-Spine.Z is positive. When a person is standing sideways and face left, Hipcenter.X-Spine.X is a minus value. Using X and Z values, it would be easy to calculate the rotation angle. Sine shoulder joints could be blocked by other parts of your body from Kinect, I chose the bone of hipcenter to spine and it worked well to track rotation of my body.

Comment: Can you please more specific about the logic?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use depths instead of calculating degrees. First detect the distance(X-axis) between right and left shoulder. Then create a proportion between this distance and angles. If the distance(i mean the distance between right and left shoulder) is max and positive, then the angle is 0. if the distance is max and negative, then the angle is 180. If the distance is max/2 and positive then the angle is 45.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old question, but I've been struggling with the same problem lately. I wrote a function that can track the rotation angle between two joints. I've tried left and right hips and it worked well for me. Mabe it will be helpful for someone else. 
The one thing is that it works well for rotation angle < 70 deg in both ways. If the angle is greater, it has difficulties to track it appropriately.
Here's my solution.

```
    protected double TrackJointsRotation(KinectSensor sensor, Joint joint1, Joint joint2)
    {
        if (joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked
            || joint2.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
            return double.NaN;

        var rightHip = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(joint1.Position, sensor.DepthStream.Format);
        var leftHip = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(joint2.Position, sensor.DepthStream.Format);

        return (Math.Atan(((double)rightHip.Depth - leftHip.Depth) / ((double)leftHip.X - rightHip.X)) * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
```